How to put missing files on halium Project manually without "repo command"
After syncing BIG halium project many many ......times  "repo sync -c -j16 (-j2)  I finished. with missing files for different errors  so I clone this missing files successfully in one folder with git --depth=1 , I want to put them in right path using "manifest repo default.xml" no problem so far ()I think
But i am confusing how to add additional branches because --DEPTH1 ,
2- is manifesting and building process in project proceed normally.
Thanks for all superusers

After some days i understand that "repo" is different with git ,repo support manifesting but "git" not ,so i cant add external repositories to repo main folder even with true sources and branches that created in "default.xml"  , because effect  synchronization and manifest process  . although ,cloning  with repo require good internet connection and fast cpu  .
